# How to find the parameters for a VSCode command in executeCommands()

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to write a vscode extension and use `vscode.commands.executeCommands()`, but I don't know what parameters the command I want to use takes.

For example, when I want to use the `"actions.find"` command, how do I find out what parameters this specific API accepts?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any *comprehensive* documentation on commands and their arguments at this time. [This page](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands) does list some of the most important ones though.

For some commands, there's also `args` auto-completion in `keybindings.json`:

[image]

Note that a lot of the built-in commands aren't much of an "API" at all. [Looking at its implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/17de08a829e56657e44213a70cf69d18f06e74a5/src/vs/editor/contrib/find/findController.ts#L445), `"actions.find"` in particular does not seem to support any arguments that would be useful to extensions. Compare this to the [implementation of `"workbench.action.findInFiles"`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/17de08a829e56657e44213a70cf69d18f06e74a5/src/vs/workbench/contrib/search/browser/searchActions.ts#L160-L188), which supports a well-defined set of arguments such as search query etc.

Comment: Appreciate! Thank you!

Comment: It's a pity `actions.find` doesn't support a "reverse search" (backwards search) boolean option, so that as you start typing it looks for the closest match *above* :/