# How to get list of all commands and related parameters for vscode so it is possible to invoke command programmatically

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I would like to have a list of all supported commands and corresponding parameters, so it is possible to execute a given command based on

```js
vscode.commands.executeCommand('<command>', params)
```

Particularly, I'm interested in 'editor.action.goToDeclaration' command.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59300624/how-to-use-vscode-executecommands/59303952

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of built-in commands [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands). This document lists a subset of Visual Studio Code commands that you might use with `vscode.commands.executeCommand` API.

> VS Code includes a large set of built-in commands that you can use to
>   interact with the editor, control the user interface, or perform
>   background operations. Many extensions also expose their core
>   functionality as commands that users and other extensions can
>   leverage.

You can find more info about using this commands or registering new commands also in the docs [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/command).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't think it is a complete list. I'm looking for some building blocks such as go and open this 'LSP.Location'

Comment: There is no complete list that includes the parameters for each command.